# Graphing MLE as a function of variance with some fixed $n$.

Tags: statistics, variance, maximum-likelihood

I am given an maximum likelihood estimator of $\sigma ^{2}$ which is $MLE=\frac{2\sigma ^{4}}{n-1}$. When $n=10$, I have to graph this formula as a function of $\sigma ^{2}$.

Does that mean I create a sequence of $\sigma ^{2}$ values?

```
variance = seq(1, 100, 0.1)
```

Then create a function for this formula?

```
mle = function(variance)
{
formula = 2*variance^{2}/9
}
```

Is this the correct function though?

Comment: To be honest, I thought this question was going to be about probabilistically plotting the characters "MSE" as in "Math StackExchange."

Comment: @AOrtiz To be honest, I accidentally said MSE instead of MLE, so we are on the same boat.

Comment: Cross posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/375637/graphing-mle-as-a-function-of-variance.